# How to make layout automatically fill window size

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I have a problem that the layout cannot automatically fill the window when the window changes its size. So how to make this layout to fill the window whenever the windows resizes?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200,40)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setText("LABEL")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

I want the line always to fill the width of window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create a new widget, you have to use the layouts properly, first place the QLabel with the QLineEdit inside a QHBoxLayout. then we put the layout with a QSpacerItem in a QVBoxLayout as I show below:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200,40)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("LABEL")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.vlayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 245, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.vlayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Another option is to use QFormLayout:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200,40)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        flayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        flayout.addRow("LABEL", self.lineEdit)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `(20,245` in `QSpacerItem`?

Comment: It is the QSpacerItem size by default, it has a width of 20 and a height of 245, the QSpacerItem is like an elastic.

Comment: And how to move the position of this layout?

Comment: What do you mean by moving the position?

Comment: I mean the layout's y-axis position, the distance between the line and the top edge of the window.

Comment: If you put it in a layout it handles those properties using its policies, ie the functions move () and setGeometry () will not work, a possible option is to place a suitable QSpacerItem. The idea of the QLayouts (QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayouts, etc) is to manage the sizes and positions managing the policies that we establish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161386/discussion-between-user6456568-and-eyllanesc).